# Why does a SVN branch jump with 100 revisions difference after commit?

Tags: svn, repository, revision

I just made a commit with my local changes related to revision 448. After that I noticed revision 549, So what's wrong now .... Any Ideas ( Not that is a big of a deal, but I can't explain it and make me wander ...) ?

I did remember making a branch though, that should be the problem I guess but it's kinda strange.

Comment: See the svn log and find out yourself.

Comment: Revision: 548
Author: deyan.dobromirov
Date: Tuesday, 01 September, 2015 3:49:52 PM
Message: ( Not important )


Revision: 482
Author: deyan.dobromirov
Date: Tuesday, 01 September, 2015 11:55:03 AM
Message: ( Not important )

Comment: OK, so in the span of about 4 hours, there were 100 commits made to the repository which didn't touch the code you were working on. That's not a bad thing, it just means that you have either a very large repository or a very active group of developers. Be glad that people are committing regularly! Or, someone might have an overzealous deploy script that's doing a lot of tagging.

Comment: So far only I contribute to this [repo](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/TrackAssemblyTool), that's why I thought that it was rather strange. But may be the [repo](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/TrackAssemblyTool) is quite large as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deyan, Alvaro almost hit source of problem, but I'll show it in details. I don't know all internals of GitHub's SVN-bridge, but exposed SVN-side of your repo seems (for pure SVN man) as "cheated", because

- SVN history is linear
- Bigger revision-id must mean "later date of commit"
- Revision-id is autoincrement counter

but

- svn log in range 482:483 seems, well, strange

> ```
> r484 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-08-10 10:07:54 +0500 (Пн, 10 авг 2015)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r483 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-08-10 10:05:34 +0500 (Пн, 10 авг 2015)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r482 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-09-01 13:55:03 +0500 (Вт, 01 сен 2015)
> ```

(note dates of 483+ revision **before** 482)

- with fast eye-search I see some "missing" revisions

> ```
> r552 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-09-01 18:36:55 +0500 (Вт, 01 сен 2015)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r550 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-09-01 17:49:52 +0500 (Вт, 01 сен 2015)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r548 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-09-01 17:49:52 +0500 (Вт, 01 сен 2015)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> r186 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-01-28 14:35:30 +0500 (Ср, 28 янв 2015)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r184 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-01-28 12:23:56 +0500 (Ср, 28 янв 2015)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

- Github states "284 commits" in single branch master, but SVN think

> ```
> >svn log -q -r HEAD
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> r554 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-09-01 19:08:39 +0500 (Вт, 01 сен 2015)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

*On the rights of delirium*: 554 is 284*2 without 14 somehow lost commits

Additional notes: when I cloned your repo with Mercurial (Hg can clone both Git and SVN repos), for Git-source I got 284 commits, as expected, for SVN-source I'm awaiting (in the process, it's long procedure) the same result as it was for SVN-client with SVN-URL: 554

---

### Intermediate preliminary diagnosis

SVN-interface to your repo is **hardly broken**, you have to inform GitHub tech-support about this issue and ask for help

### Further explorations

For "good" GitHub repository, cloning from Git and SVN URLs must provide the same results (the same repos), but your SVN-repo is extremely dirty: a lot of branches (unknown to Git)

```
lol                          543:f585d0a8ee89 (closed)
LuaDB                        541:816e1f7df77f (closed)
TimerOsClock                 344:a4bf94c50012 (closed)
Timer-os.clock()             343:27e5c55368d8 (closed)
VariableSpace                316:69a4aa153a0c (closed)
GhostAllProps                313:13352bdb9fb0 (closed)
CashePoolTest                183:a90989b79d70 (closed)
```

a lot of duplicated commit to these ghostly branches (1, 2, 3 on screenshot), non-linear history (**totally impossible** for SVN): see (only part of) children for r401 (marked with black circles)

[image: Repo-log]

### Final recommendations

Don't use Github for SVN-projects with a lot of branching in SVN-style blindly, it's bridge become crazy and unpredictable. Github is good for linear SVN-development and, at last but not least, SVN-access is "tool of last resort" for real Git repositories behind the scene, not ready for any hard use-cases

Comment: I can't since the tortoise Git ( My best option so far ) sometimes does not want to run my pre-commit hook, as it happens randomly, sometimes not at all. Git for windows is messed up. I can't work with that, because I know what I want to do, but it gives 2-3 buttons and that's it and also it can't be set-up to support proxies and custom network settings e.g.

Comment: You might want to try SourceTree if you use Windows 7 or greater.

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров - move to another hosting with SVN? Use another Git-client (GitShell|SmartGit|etc...)? Use another DVCS (Mercurial with TortoiseHG+HGGit|HGSubversion - recommended by me way)?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind revision numbers are global across the entire repository.  [From the red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs):

> ...revision N represents the state of the repository filesystem after the Nth commit

So, someone or even yourself has made 100 commits to somewhere else in the repository such as the trunk or another branch.

Comment: That's true, but in one commit, it seems a little harsh, thou I just reordered about 10 lines ...

Comment: Why is it "harsh"? It just means that other work has been happening in the repository since your last commit.

Comment: Nope, as I said, I am the only contributor

Answer (score 0):

If the repository you're talking about is [TrackAssemblyTool](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/TrackAssemblyTool), the fact that it's hosted at GitHub suggests it's using, well, *git* as main source control tool. Whatever, there's actually a Subversion repository at that URL which gets exposed if you use a Subversion client to fetch it. Apparently it's a [GitHub feature](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/):

> GitHub supports Subversion clients via the HTTPS protocol. We use a
>   Subversion bridge to communicate svn commands to GitHub.

Said that, you only need to check the logs:

```
C:\>svn log -r 448:549 https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/TrackAssemblyTool
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r448 | dvdvideo1234 | 2015-08-25 16:56:04 +0200 (ma., 25 ago. 2015) | 2 lines

test

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r449 | dvdvideo1234 | 2015-08-25 16:56:26 +0200 (ma., 25 ago. 2015) | 2 lines

sdf

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r450 | dvdvideo1234 | 2015-08-25 16:58:20 +0200 (ma., 25 ago. 2015) | 2 lines

go

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r451 | dvdvideo1234 | 2015-08-25 17:00:11 +0200 (ma., 25 ago. 2015) | 2 lines

go
```

[...]

```
r546 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-08-31 22:01:33 +0200 (lu., 31 ago. 2015) | 1 line

Fixed loop bug Works 100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r547 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-09-01 10:55:03 +0200 (ma., 01 sep. 2015) | 1 line

Localizing some functions, updating the Lua table sorting
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r548 | deyan.dobromirov | 2015-09-01 14:49:52 +0200 (ma., 01 sep. 2015) | 3 lines

Shortened the TOOL:LeftClick() better data flow
Changed Cvar abbreviation
Updated Undo custom messages
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can browse the equivalent git commits with [GitHub interface](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/TrackAssemblyTool/commits/master).

If your log was missing revisions, you most likely weren't pointing to the repository root but some other location.

Comment: I was committing those to test the hook. Is that why this thing happened. May be I should just delete it and start over.

Comment: I did check the logs, but TortoiseSVN does not provide the information such as that. As I recall I did run the log ( The second comment in the post ) and it showed me 

`log: Revision: 548`
`log: Author: deyan.dobromirov`
`log: Date: Tuesday, 01 September, 2015 3:49:52 `
`log: Revision: 482`
`log: Author: deyan.dobromirov`
`log: Date: Tuesday, 01 September, 2015 11:55:03`

Where can I see such information. I remember making a branch and deleting it though.

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров Check the [Repository Browser](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html): «The context menu for a folder allows you to: Show the revision log for that folder»

Comment: I Already did that.... look at the second post and the one above it

http://postimg.org/image/keyo41g1r/

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров This last screenshot doesn't feature the Repo-browser log (window title starts with "E:\"). It's probably a working copy log so it'll omit revisions outside your working copy root (`/trunk/lua`, I presume).

Comment: But version control is about syncing your code across multiple machines is it not ? If you hit update it will just download all the history about the project

Comment: What does this have to do with all this? How does the ability to display history from a given path prevent Subversion from "syncing your code across multiple machines"? I'm terribly sorry but I think I lost track of your precise worries a while ago. I hope Lazy Badger's awesome helped you sort out your issues.