# How to export github branch repos?

Tags: git, svn, github

We can export `fractional` github `master` repos below,

```
$ svn export https://github.com/user_name/repos_name/trunk/dir_name
```

Howerver, I failed to do it on `branch` repos below,

```
$ svn export https://github.com/user_name/repos_name/branch_name/dir_name

(Error: doesn't exist.)
```

Comment: `svn ls https://github.com/user_name/repos_name/branch_name/` ??? SVN branches on GitHub is  **A Big Headache**, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332269/why-does-a-svn-branch-jump-with-100-revisions-difference-after-commit/32345978#32345978 JFYI

Comment: `svn ls ...` came up with same err: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist.

Comment: reduce URL to one level, but I suppose and predict - there are not branches at all (except `master`) in Git-repo

Comment: @ Lazy Badger Thanks. I already checked with `svn ls .../repos_name` then `master` and `branches` did show up. However, `svn ls .../repos_name/trunk`, `svn ls .../repos_name/branches` , `svn ls .../repos_name/branches/branch_name` or `svn ls .../repos_name/branch_name` got same err as before.

Comment: @ Lazy Badger Suddenly, the targets to `trunk`, `branches` and `branches/branch_name` all work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@Solution**

Now it seems to work below,

```
$ svn ls https://github.com/user_name/repos_name
```

=> `trunk` `branches`

```
$ svn export https://github.com/user_name/repos_name/branches/branch_name/path_to_dir
```

Additionally, each file is hooked with a `raw` link, just `wget [link]` to grab it.